# Is there a usage in singlethreaded code where std::shared_ptr is more appropriate than std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, std, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

my understanding of the new memory `<memory>`header in C++11 is a bit week, but from what I can tell shared_ptr is refcounted ptr that makes it really really expensive to copy it(esp on for example ARM arch). And unique_ptr is pretty much the very very light wrapper around new/delete. And it is movable, so it is not like are limited by the scope where you created it.
So my question is:
is there a singlethreaded code usage where shared_ptr is prefered to unique_ptr?

Im not interested in answers like: making your singlethreaded code ready for future multithreading. Presume code is and will stay singlthreaded.

Comment: `shared_ptr`s don't have anything to do with multithreading. A `unique_ptr` works perfectly in multithreaded code, at least for the prupose it's made for, which is entirely different from `shared_ptr`'s purpose.

Comment: @ChristianRau your comments to Ernest answer are really good, I suggest you std::accumulate :) them into the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dwelling on threading here is kind of a red herring; there's a clear contrast between the two, and it has little to nothing to do with threads. If you're using these classes in a single-threaded environment, you may be able to turn off the atomic operations support; for example, with Boost, define  the macro `BOOST_SP_DISABLE_THREADS`.

You use `shared_ptr<>` when you're not quite sure what the lifetime of an object will be, and want "the last guy in the room to shut off the lights" -- i.e., you don't want the object to be deleted until no client is using it any longer. You use `unique_ptr<>` when you know exactly who is going to delete the object -- i.e., when the lifetime of the pointed-to object is precisely delimitated by a scope.

It is true that copying a `shared_ptr<>` is not free, but it's *far* from "really, really expensive." You pay a little bit for the reference counting overhead, but that's the whole point of using it: you need to keep track of the clients of the object; there's a little cost involved, but you get the benefit of not leaking the object.

Comment: "when you're not quite sure what the lifetime of an object will be, and want "the last guy in the room to shut off the lights"" - doesnt std::move enables this with unique_ptr also?

Comment: "and it has little to nothing to do with threads." also shared_ptr uses atomic instructions to do the refcounting, no reason to do this in singlethreaded code

Comment: `move` lets you change ownership of a `unique_ptr`, explicitly, whereas `shared_ptr` can have multiple owners, so they have quite different semantics.

Comment: I still cant see where you want multiple owners in single threded code. I mean if you call more than one function that take unique ptr as argument you are obviously in a problem because first move will set callers unique_ptr to null, but if you change your functions to take raw ptr or unique_ptr ref(not unreasonable imho) you can call{... f1(sp); f2(sp); f3(sp);}

Comment: what im saying: please provide code example where unique_ptr "fails"  to do the job

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl A very good example (and one where reference counting has always been used) is a scenegraph hierarchy. Say you want multiple objects in a scene graph to use the same geomtry or the same texture. Of course you want the actual geometry/texture data to stay alive as long as any object uses it. But on the other hand you don't want to manage it separately somewhere else and when no object uses it anymore, the data should be freed. So this is a perfect example of all the objects having shared ownership of the data and freeing it once nobody needs it anymore.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Of course managing such resources in a separate component would also be an option, but then you have to explicitly free them once nobody uses them anymore. And this also breaks down once you want to share complete subgraphs of the scenegraph and your possibilities of explicitly managing ownership of each and every scene component shrink even further.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Of course I also have the opinion that `shared_ptr`s should be used with care and only when neccessary (and shouldn't be spammed overall just to not care about any memory managemant at all), and usually `unique_ptr`s or raw pointers are more appropriate. But they nevertheless still have their use cases.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very good question.

In a multi-threaded build one basically always pays for atomic reference counter increments/decrements made by `shared_ptr<>`, even if objects never get shared between threads.

The other drawback is that the size of `shared_ptr<>` is double the size of a plain pointer.

For these two reasons `shared_ptr<>` has never been a good choice for performance critical applications.

Multi-threaded applications have a few types of objects that are shared between thread and the majority that are not. Using atomic reference counter increment/decrement is only required for the thread-shared objects and it is silly to pay atomic operation costs for the majority of other objects. Hence it makes good sense to have different (base) types for thread-shared and thread-non-shared objects and manage them using `boost::intrusive_ptr<>`. Thread-shared objects have an atomic reference counter while thread-non-shared object get a plain integer counter. E.g.:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>

template<class Derived, class Counter>
class RefCounter
{
    Counter ref_count_;

    friend void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(RefCounter* p) {
        ++p->ref_count_;
    }

    friend void intrusive_ptr_release(RefCounter* p) {
        if(!--p->ref_count_)
            delete static_cast<Derived*>(p);
    }

protected:
    RefCounter() : ref_count_() {}
};

class NonThreadShared
    : public RefCounter<NonThreadShared, unsigned>
{};

class ThreadShared
    : public RefCounter<ThreadShared, std::atomic<unsigned> >
{};

int main() {
    boost::intrusive_ptr<NonThreadShared> p(new NonThreadShared);
    boost::intrusive_ptr<ThreadShared> q(new ThreadShared);
}
```